# Slim Framework 3: Create Restfull webservice

Tags: json, slim

I am building a restfull webservice that returns json using Slim Framework 3.
**What is the best way to do this**? Should I use a framework or a middleware.

I tried a middleware but the problem is that I need to have routes that returns **json** and other routes that returns **normal html**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off using a framework. But in the end, it comes down to how large your application is, and how complicated it gets to maintain big chunks of code. All a framework does is make your life easier by abstracting spagettie code.

Middleware is best suited for authentication, caching and the likes. You don't have direct access to route params in the middleware.

You can easily get away with just smart app routing. Make use of route grouping and mapping in slim, they are very useful.

Here's a neat trick I know. Add a middleware to a group by simple doing this:

```
$app->group(..., ...)->add(middleware class or function goes here);
```

By doing so you limit the middleware's presence to just that group. It's useful for setting headers and performing authentication.

#### Json Response

As for generating a JSON response, I recommend that you use the following technique:

```
return $res->withJson(data)->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Note, that you are suppose to pass raw data. The method withJson will do the encoding for you. You also should return the response immediately after you set the headers, as I am doing above. If you don't do so, the headers will not be set.

Comment: Is there something you recommend for outputting json, or should I just write it myself?